# Add a new assignment operator

Tags: operator-overloading, variable-assignment, smalltalk, pharo, squeak

I started using smalltalk and I am trying to add a new assignment operator `:>`.

The current operator used in pharo is no selector so I started to look into the class Scanner where the underscore `_` can be enabled for assignments. I've tried to do it in a similar way but it did not work.

Do you have any idea or suggestion about how I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

For a start, have a look at the Method `Scanner>>#xColon`. This method is called whenever a colon is encountered in the input. By adding the following snippet to the top of the method, you can make it detect your new assignment token `:>`:

```
aheadChar = $> ifTrue: [
  self step.
  tokenType := #leftArrow.
  self step.
  ^ token := #':=' ]
```

Like this `:>` behaves exactly like the normal assignment. By customising `tokenType` and `token` you can pass your new assignment operator to the parser (see `Parser>>#expression` and `Parser>>#assignment:`) and build a different AST (i.e. to achieve a different execution behaviour).

If you are interested in more flexibility you might want to look at [Helvetia](http://scg.unibe.ch/research/helvetia). Helvetia is a language workbench for Pharo that allows you to modify the host language and adapt the tools in a more modular fashion. One of the [examples](http://scg.unibe.ch/research/helvetia/examples#45069628) included with the distribution (`CUSwapExample`) is adding two new assignment operators to Smalltalk.